# Facades in laravel 8 Is perfectly working in controller file but i want to use on facade function in blade file not working

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Facades in `Laravel 8` Are perfectly working in the controller file but I want to use on facade function in the blade file not working

**error:**

```
Error Call to undefined method App\PaymentGateway\PaymentFacade::process() (View: D:\alpha\resources\views\admin\auth\register_coverage.blade.php)
```

**On Blade file, this is facade function **

```
{{ \Payment::process() }}  //// this is  not working
```

**Controller file**

```
public function registerStore(Request $request) {
   dd(Payment::process());   ///// this is working 
}
```

I want to know the solution to this problem.

**Payment File**

```
<?php 

namespace App\PaymentGateway;

class Payment {

    public static function process(){

        return "testing";

    }

}
```

**PaymentFacade File**

```
<?php 

namespace App\PaymentGateway\Facades;

class PaymentFacade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(){

        return 'payment';
    }

}
```

**PaymentServiceProvier File**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\PaymentGateway\Payment;

class PaymentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('payment',function(){
        return new Payment;
    });
}

/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}
}
```

**Config/app file**

```
'providers' => [ App\Providers\PaymentServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [ 'Payment'=> App\PaymentGateway\Facades\PaymentFacade::class,

],
```

Comment: Instead of `{{ \Payment::process() }}` you need to define full path e.g like `{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Payment::process() }}`

Comment: I have also tried this but not working

Comment: `App\PaymentGateway\PaymentFacade` is this path for your facade is correct?

Comment: {{ \App\PaymentGateway\PaymentFacade::process() }}   i have used this   and u r right for my path .

Comment: what is `Payment` class ? coming from

Comment: namespace App\PaymentGateway;


 class Payment {

    public static function process(){

        return "testing";

    }


 }

this is my Payment Class

Comment: Have you tried adding the Facade to the `aliases` array in you `config/app.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend the base Facade class. Change App/PaymentGateway/Facades/PaymentFacade.php to

```
<?php

namespace App\PaymentGateway\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class PaymentFacade extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(){

        return 'payment';
    }

}
```

Comment: 'Payment'=> App\PaymentGateway\PaymentFacade::class,

i have already used this in app file .   lots of time i have used composer dump-autoload

Comment: Error
Call to undefined method App\PaymentGateway\Facades\PaymentFacade::process()

'Payment'=> App\PaymentGateway\Facades\PaymentFacade::class,

Comment: yes friend i have created 
'Payment'=> App\PaymentGateway\Facades\PaymentFacade::class,

Comment: i have updated my question with more brief kindly review it

Comment: Please delete comments that are not relevent to this answer.